# Char value higher then 255?

Tags: c, encryption, char

Today I wrote simple program to encryption my .txt file. And I saw, I can set char value higher than 255. 
This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
FILE* fp;
FILE* fp2;
char buffor = '\0';
int szyfr = 0;

if(argc < 4)
{
    printf("Za malo argumentow (c/dc, sciezka, szyfr)!\n");
    exit(0);
}

{
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < strlen(argv[3]);++i)
    {
        szyfr *= 10;
        szyfr += argv[3][i]-48;
    }
}

if(!strncmp(argv[1], "c", 1))
{
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fp2 = fopen("crypted.data", "w");
    if(!fp)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file: %s!", argv[2]);
        exit(0);
    }

    while(1) 
    {
        buffor = fgetc(fp);
        if(feof(fp) != 0) break;
        fputc(buffor+szyfr, fp2); 
    }

    fputc_unlocked(
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}
else if(!strncmp(argv[1], "dc", 2))
{
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fp2 = fopen("uncrypted.txt", "w");
    if(!fp)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file: %s!", argv[2]);
        exit(0);
    }

    while(1) 
    {
        buffor = fgetc(fp);
        if(feof(fp) != 0) break;
        fputc(buffor-szyfr, fp2); 
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
}

return 0;
}
```

Whatever you set in the szyfr value this will work, but chars in the .data file is very strange (for example for 666 szyfr it will be like "    ×ýû¤") 
Why this doesn't giving error about char memory or something like that?

PS: Sorry for some texts in code in Polish but I forgot about this

Comment: I guess binary addition overflow ? read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: In order to use 16-bit unicode or other non-8-bit text you will need to use a wchar.

Comment: `char` is usually 8-bit wide. Whether it's signed (-128..127) or unsigned (0..255) varies by machine/compiler. You need 21 bits to represent any Unicode Code Point (0..0x10FFFF)

Comment: Thank you for answers, I will use wchar to encryption now

Comment: Don't use the `feof()` function to decide when to finish a loop. Use the value returned by the input function. In this case, `fgetc(fp)` will return the value `EOF` to indicate that there's no more input to process.

Comment: Your code does not compile. The call to `fputc_unlocked` is incomplete, perhaps a copy/paste error. What behavior of your code makes you think you're using `char` values greater than 255?

Comment: @Grifplex Please don't mess up beginner with `wchar_t`, wide character should not be used anymore and they are not design to handle UTF16 !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I saw, I can set char value higher than 255.

I guess you're talking about the first argument to `fputc()`, and maybe about the return value of `fgetc()`.  These both have type `int`, but that doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.  The behavior of both functions is defined in terms of type `unsigned char`:

**`fgetc()`**:

> the `fgetc` function obtains that character **as an unsigned char converted to an int** [...]

([C2011, 2.21.7.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1p2); emphasis added)

**`fputc()`**:

> The `fputc` function writes the character specified by `c` (**converted to an unsigned char**) to the output stream pointed to by `stream` [...]

([C2011, 2.21.7.3/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.3p2); emphasis added)

So yes, inasmuch as the range of type `int` is, in practice, invariably larger than that of type `unsigned char`, you can pass a value larger than `unsigned char` can represent to `fputc()`.  But no, that does not result in writing that value in a manner that can be read back.  The conversion to `unsigned char` will result in the character actually written being in the range of `unsigned char`, which is almost certainly 0 - 255 for you.

> Why this doesn't giving error about char memory or something like that?

There is no error in `fputc()` because the behavior is perfectly well defined for the arguments you are providing.  Even if there were an error, however, your code would not tell you, because such an error would be communicated to your program via the return value of `fputc()`, which you do not check.

**Regarding wide-character I/O**

Note that wide-character I/O functions such as `fgetwc()` and `fputwc()` operate in larger units, but their underlying behavior is not fundamentally different.  It involves casting analogous to that performed by `fgetc()` and `fputc()` -- thus affording the same possibility of data corruption -- and you might still see strange characters in your encrypted file, albeit probably different ones.

**Regarding strange characters**

As far as strange characters appearing in the encrypted file, this is pretty much to be expected, albeit somewhat dependent on what your editor or terminal (depending on how you display the file) supposes is the file's character encoding.  Your encryption scheme effectively converts character data to binary data, so it's unreasonable to expect it to look like character data.

Comment: Thank you for that complete explain. Yes, I wanna this stranger files, because this is encrypter, but I didn't know why I didn't have errors. Now I know, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

C is a low-level language that just does what you tell it, with no help or argument.

You declare a variable `buffor` to be a `char`, and then you call a function `fgetc()` that returns an `int`, and then you assign it. C says "Fine. You've asked me to put 16 gallons of water into an 8-gallon bucket, so I did." Now you've got a full 8 gallon bucket and a wet floor.  C just chops off 8 bits and drops them, so for instance, you'll never be able to tell when `fgetc()` returns EOF, since that's a larger-than-8-bit value.

If you want to assure that 8-bit variables only get 8-bit values, you'll have to check them yourself before you assign them.

Comment: Are you saying that `fgetc` returned a value greater than 255? Assuming 8-bit bytes, that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: deserve a downvote for using **** unit :p (joke this is not me).

Comment: @KeithThompson The range of `fgetc()` include EOF, [0..255]. Suppose that unsigned char are 8 bit so this doesn't fit into a unsigned char.

Comment: @Stargateur: Correct -- but `EOF` is negative, and `fgetc` should never return a value exceeding `UCHAR_MAX`, which is typically 256. The value returned by `fgetc` should always be stored in an `int` object, not a `char`, so you can distinguish `EOF` from any valid character value.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you're saying.  You're correct that storing the result of `fgetc()` in a `char` object can lose information, but the OP's question was about a `char` value exceeding 255. I don't think the `EOF` issue is the source of the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: Thanks for explain Daniel

Comment: I agree, it was just a handy example from his own code to illustrate the greater point of "why can I store a big number in a char without an error".

Comment: You might consider updating your answer to address the specific problem the OP was asking about.

Comment: I think the accepted answer does that nicely. I like it when other answers are available that look at the question from a different point of view.